# Create file / folder

Tags: java, android, file

How can I create a folder or file with the current date and time and in a specific directory?

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd HHmmss") ;
LocalDateTime ldtFile = LocalDateTime.parse(fileName, f) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo") ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(z) ;
LocalDateTime ldtThreeDaysAgo = zdtNow.minusDays(3).toLocalDateTime() ;

if(ldtFile.isAfter(ldtThreeDaysAgo)) 
{
     ....
}
```

I tried this example but it didn’t work for me as it is for Java 8+.

Comment: The example code you found seems to be for parsing a filename to extract a date time.  That's the opposite of what you are trying to do.   (And that code should be compatible with API version 26 and later ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it:

```
        public static String ArchiveDir;
        
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf.applyPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
        File sdPath = new File(AppPathData() + "/Archive/" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        sdPath.mkdirs();
        ArchiveDir = sdPath.getAbsolutePath();
        return ArchiveDir;
```